# winapi doesn't respond to keypress

Tags: c++, winapi

I recently decided to learn a bit of WinApi, but I hit a snag. I want to display a massage in my window after a keypress, but it doesn't seem to work. If I press the key multiple times or if I hold it down, still nothing happens. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is the full code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND   hwnd,
                          UINT   uMsg,
                          WPARAM wParam,
                          LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    LPCWSTR display_str = L"hello";
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
            {
            TextOut(hdc,
                    15, 15,
                    display_str,
                    _tcslen(display_str));
            }
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG uMsg;
    HINSTANCE hInst;
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    LPCWSTR class_name = L"myWindowClass";

    wcex.cbSize         = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = class_name;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Call to RegisterClassEx failed!", L"Win32 Guided Tour!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hInst = hInstance;

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL,
        class_name,
        L"Test",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        200, 200,
        740, 540,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
        );

    if(!hwnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&uMsg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&uMsg);
        DispatchMessage(&uMsg);
    }
    return uMsg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to be processing keyboard notification messages.

Comment: Windows does not repeatedly paint the window like a game or monitor does every 1/60 of a second. Windows only paints the window when it needs to. Your current approach will not work. You'll need to look for keyboard messages and ask to be painted, not the other way around. Be sure to read MSDN's introduction to the Windows painting model.

Comment: You need [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows®-Fifth-Developer-Reference/dp/157231995X). Used copies are cheap. Get one if you want to learn the Windows API. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Windows sends [WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx) message when a key is pressed. In `WndProc` handle WM_KEYDOWN message, call [InvalidateRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002(v=vs.85).aspx) with the Client rect of the window and draw the text you want to display in WM_PAINT message handler.

Comment: You don't draw text in a `WM_KEYDOWN` message handler. You invalidate the portion of the window that should be repainted in response to a key press. All painting is performed in the `WM_PAINT` handler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my example, if pressed F11 key, print in console string.:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
     if(wParam==VK_F11)
     {
           std::cout << "Hello in my example!";
     }

break;
```